# Does Java need .class files to run even if defined

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started Java today and I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError when I run my code:

```
class Example {

    public static final String greeting = "Hi there";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.format("%s", Example.greeting);
    }
}
```

Above is the contents of my `example.java` code. This code compiles fine in the Eclipse execution, but when I try to run `example.java` by itself, it fails. Eclipse also created some `.class` file when I ran this program, but that doesn't make much sense as to why it would fail if I ran the `.java` by itself in a different directory as all the information of the `class Example` is found in the `.java` file itself.

Does Java need the `.class` file to compile and run despite having the class itself defined in the program and why? I also built the `.java` file through terminal and it worked fine

Comment: where is the Student  class?

Comment: You cannot run a .java file, it's just a piece of text. You need a .class file.

Comment: .java contains the code and .class contains the bytecode to be interpreted by the JVM. Also all the classes required to run the program should be in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Sorry, the "Student" static variable is actually Example, mispelt it on StackOverflow

Comment: if you have time, read this tutorial. will enlight you and solve some of your future doubts about java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation and execution of a Java program is two step process:

- During compilation phase Java compiler compiles the source code and generates `bytecode`. This intermediate `bytecode` is saved in form of a `.class file`.
- In second phase, Java virtual machine (JVM) also called Java interpreter takes the `.class` as input and generates output by executing the `bytecode`.

So yes `.class` file is essential for execution of the code. `.java` file is text that you write, but not what the machine can interpret.

Here is the flow diagram of what happens:

[image]

**To look at it in more depth:**

When your Java project builds, it translates the source code (contained in `*.java` source files) to Java `bytecode` (most often contained in `*.class` files). This takes your high-level code one step closer to machine code, but not quite there yet. **This `bytecode` is a collection of compact instructions; easier for a machine to interpret, but less readable.**

When you run a Java application on your computer, cellphone, or any other Java-enabled platform, you essentially pass this Java `bytecode` to the Java Virtual Machine. The interpreter in the Java Virtual Machine usually starts compiling the entire `bytecode` at runtime, following the principles of so-called *just-in-time* compilation. This makes for the typical, albeit often slight delay when opening a Java application, but generally enhances the program performance compared to interpreted compilation.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Java need the .class file to compile and run despite having the class itself defined in the program and why

The compiled output of a java file (class) is `.class` file. It contains the `bytecode` of the program which is run by the JVM. So `.class` files are required to run the program.

> I also built the .java file through terminal and it worked fine

Even through the terminal, when you compile the `.java` file (class). It creates the `.class` for each class declared in the `.java` file. Then you execute the class which contains the `main` method. The `main` method is the entry point for the JVM.

> For example:
>   **File name:** example.java
>   **Compile code:** javac example.java
>   **Output is .class file:** `Example.class`. Because name of the class is `Example`.
>   **Run the program:** java Example

> Error in your code.  **Looks like this has been updated in the question.**

```
System.out.format("%s", Student.greeting);
```

Name of the class is `Example` not `Student`. it should be:

```
System.out.format("%s", Example.greeting);
```